# Validate datetimes in multiple formats

Tags: asp.net, datetime, unobtrusive-validation

To output a datetime as a hidden, I am using a html helper like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Foobar.Date)
```

This outputs an element where value is in this format:

> 2014-11-07 00:00:00

and the validator expects datetime values in this format (without seconds):

> 2014-11-07 00:00

How can I have the validator accept both formats?

I am including validation like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js")"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js")"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I could add a client side validator very simple like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element, parameters)
{        
    return value.match(/^\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+(:\d+)?$/) != null;
});
```

to have the client side validation let values both with and without seconds to pass.

The server side seems to accept both formats (double checked).

Answer (score 0):

Then set Format which is recognized by Validator:

```
$("#DiscountPromoCodeValidFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",     
    timeFormat:  "HH:mm",
    onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#DiscountPromoCodeValidUntil").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
});
```